# Proxybroker - AttributeError 'dict' object has no attribute 'expired'

Tags: python-3.x, proxybroker

Well I have this weird problem. Same script works on windows7 and on windows10 throws AttributeError. And I just can't figure out what is the difference.

This is py code:

```
import asyncio
from proxybroker import Broker

async def use(proxies):
    while True:
        proxy = await proxies.get()
        if proxy is None:
            break
        elif 'SOCKS5' in proxy.types:  # filter by type
            print('Found SOCKS5 proxy: %s' % proxy)
        else:
            print('Found proxy: %s' % proxy)

async def find(proxies, loop):
    broker = Broker(queue=proxies,
                    timeout=8,
                    attempts_conn=3,
                    max_concurrent_conn=200,
                    judges=['https://httpheader.net/', 'http://httpheader.net/'],
                    providers=['http://www.proxylists.net/', 'http://fineproxy.org/eng/'],
                    verify_ssl=False,
                    loop=loop)

    # only anonymous & high levels of anonymity for http protocol and high for others:
    types = [('HTTP', ('Anonymous', 'High')), 'HTTPS', 'SOCKS4', 'SOCKS5']
    countries = ['US', 'GB', 'DE']
    limit = 10

    await broker.find(types=types, countries=countries, limit=limit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    proxies = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
    tasks = asyncio.gather(find(proxies, loop), use(proxies))
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

And this is the error that it throws:

```
C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:/Users/draga/Desktop/Rts/PROXY/Proxy.py"
C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py:576: DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead
  warnings.warn("Use async with instead", DeprecationWarning)
C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py:72: DeprecationWarning: ClientSession.close() is not coroutine
  warnings.warn(self._msg, DeprecationWarning)
C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py:72: DeprecationWarning: ClientSession.close() is not coroutine
  warnings.warn(self._msg, DeprecationWarning)
C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py:72: DeprecationWarning: ClientSession.close() is not coroutine
  warnings.warn(self._msg, DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/draga/Desktop/Rts/PROXY/Proxy.py", line 35, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/Users/draga/Desktop/Rts/PROXY/Proxy.py", line 29, in find
    await broker.find(types=types, countries=countries, limit=limit)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\api.py", line 108, in find
    await self._run(self._checker.check_judges(), action)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\api.py", line 114, in _run
    await tasks
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\api.py", line 153, in _grab
    proxies = await task
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 452, in _wait_for_one
    return f.result()  # May raise f.exception().
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\providers.py", line 68, in get_proxies
    await self._pipe()
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\providers.py", line 101, in _pipe
    await self._find_on_page(self.url)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\providers.py", line 117, in _find_on_page
    page = await self.get(url, data=data, headers=headers, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\providers.py", line 132, in get
    page = await self._get(url, data=data, headers=headers, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\providers.py", line 144, in _get
    method, url, data=data, headers=headers) as resp:
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 637, in __aenter__
    self._resp = yield from self._coro
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 231, in _request
    conn = yield from self._connector.connect(req)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 378, in connect
    proto = yield from self._create_connection(req)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 686, in _create_connection
    _, proto = yield from self._create_direct_connection(req)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 697, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = yield from self._resolve_host(req.url.raw_host, req.port)
  File "C:\Users\draga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 666, in _resolve_host
    self._cached_hosts.expired(key):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'expired'
```

#### Update:

it seems the problem is in loop.run_until_complete(tasks) still dunno why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProxyBroker doesn't works after updating aiohttp to 2.1.0... You have to downgrade it to older version.

Comment: I spend so much time on this to figure it out and it was that simple. I did downgrade aiohttp and now it works. Thanks!